# How can I copy text in one click in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

This code works fine in Google Chrome, Opera, IE 11. But it doesn't work in Mozilla firefox and Safari. I get error in the following string
"var successful = document.execCommand('copy');"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Copy</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/npm.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="text">
            Copytextblalalalal
        </div>
        <button id="btnCopy" onclick="copyText()">COPY</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function copyText() {
        var emailLink = document.querySelector('#text');
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(emailLink);
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);

        try {
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
            console.log('Copy command was ' + msg);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
        }
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands) : "**copy**
    Copies the current selection to the clipboard. For Mozilla, clipboard capability must be enabled in the user.js preference file. See [A brief guide to Mozilla preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences) for more information."

Comment: @Kaiido this solution doesn't work. Firefox version 37.0.2

Comment: did you follow [those steps](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard) ? (didn't tried myself)

Comment: Also always though that this answer was the best solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6055620/3702797  I would hate your website so much if because of some action I wasn't aware, I do loose all the content I kept in my Clipboard

Comment: @Kaiido According to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=913734 , capability.policy.* preferences have been removed since firefox 29. The documentation is not up to date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Firefox 41 (September 2015) the copy command should be available by default when triggered from certain trusted (user-triggered) events, such as what would be fired in response to a button click. The [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Browser_Compatibility) from MDN offers further information, see also the [release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/41.0/releasenotes/).

The code in the question should therefore work. Indeed, I tested something very similar (see code below) and it worked great for me using Firefox 44.

```js
function doCopy() {
    var textToCopy = document.getElementById('textToCopy');
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(textToCopy);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('copy');
}

(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("copyTrigger");
    el.addEventListener("click", doCopy, false);
})();
```

```css
textarea {display: block; margin-top: 1em; width: 500px;}
```

```html
<div id="textToCopy">Elephant</div>
<button id="copyTrigger">Copy above text</button>
<textarea placeholder="Try pasting here to test"></textarea>
```